# How to convert this sql query to cakephp format?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can anyone please help to convert this query to cakephp format because im new to cakephp

```
SELECT t_order_product.PRODUCT_CD, m_product.PRODUCT_NAME, count(t_order_product.PRODUCT_CD) as Quantity 
from t_order_product 
JOIN m_product ON t_order_product.PRODUCT_CD = m_product.PRODUCT_CD   
where ORDER_STATUS_CD='2' 
group by PRODUCT_CD 
order by PRODUCT_CD
```

Comment: please take a look ot the help page about [**how to aks**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): you should show your efforts so far and explain what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your sql if you want to count orders for your products. You need to count the order id. Should be :

`SELECT m_product.PRODUCT_CD, m_product.PRODUCT_NAME, count(t_order_product.ID) as Quantity`

In cakephp :

```
 $datas = $this->Product->find('all',array(
            'contain'=>array(),
            'joins'=>array(
              array(
                'table'=>'t_order_product',
                'alias'=>'Order',
                'type'=>'INNER',
                'conditions'=>array(
                  'Order.PRODUCT_CD = Product.PRODUCT_CD',
                  'Order.ORDER_STATUS_CD'=>2
                )
              )
            ),
            'fields'=>array(
                'Product.PRODUCT_CD',
                'Product.PRODUCT_NAME',  
                'n'=>'count(Order.id)'
            ),
            'group'=>array(
              'Product.PRODUCT_CD'
            )
        ));
```

The result will be a array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [PRODUCT_CD] => X,
                    [PRODUCT_NAME] => XXXX,

                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(`Order`.`id`)] => n
                )

        )
    [1]....

)
```

Comment: I wanted to count the product code. The code should be inside the COntroller right?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want and the structure of your two tables.  The code should be inside the controller. For best practice, you could put it in function in the model product.  In this case change $this->Product->find... by $this->find(...